# How to fix type inference error in this fold example?

Tags: scala, type-inference

Suppose I am writing:

```
sealed trait Status
object Error1 extends Status
case class Ok(x: Int) extends Status  

def foo(opt: Option[Int]): Status = opt.fold(Error1)(x => Ok(x))
```

When I try it in REPL I get an error:

```
scala> def foo(opt: Option[Int]): Status = opt.fold(Error1)(x => Ok(x))
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
found   : Ok
required: Error1.type
   def foo(opt: Option[Int]): Status = opt.fold(Error1)(x => Ok(x))
                                                               ^
```

I can work it around but it does not look particularly elegant:

```
 // work around the type error above
 val error1: Status = Error1
 def ok(x: Int): Status = Ok(x)

 def foo(opt: Option[Int]): Status = opt.fold(error1)(x => ok(x))
```

How would you suggest solving this type problem ?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the fold? Shouldn't it receive a tuple instead of `x`? It looks like the `fold` will always return `Ok` for any list longer than 1 element.

Comment: @IlyaKogan Where do you see a list in the question ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you see `fold` infers return type from the zero/fallback value provided as first arg. There it is `Error` as it resolve the most specific type of the value.

You can annotate the fold in the following ways to indicate you want a `Status`.

```scala
opt.fold[Status](err)(x => Ok(x))
opt.fold(err: Status)(x => Ok(x))
```

Answer (score 3):

The compiler infers that the type is Error1 because that is the type of the first parameter passed to fold.

In terms of the answer to the direct question, you can tell the compiler that it is an Error1, but that the relevant type is Status, by passing the type explicitly as Status

```
sealed trait Status
object Error1 extends Status
case class Ok(x: Int) extends Status  

def foo(opt: Option[Int]): Status = opt.fold(Error1: Status)(x => Ok(x))
```

Function foo will then return as follows:

```
scala> foo(Option(5))
res0: Status = Ok(5)
```

Answer (score 3):

fold signature looks like:

```
final def fold[B](ifEmpty: ⇒ B)(f: (A) ⇒ B): B
```

So, it is a curried function with a type parameter `B`. So it first executes `opt.fold(Error1)` and infers that B is `Error1`. So, the second part `(x => Ok(x))` should be `(f: (A) => Error1)`, and for that reason the compiler complains.

You can fix it being explicit with the type as follows:

```
scala> def foo(opt: Option[Int]): Status = opt.fold[Status](Error1)(x => Ok(x))
foo: (opt: Option[Int])Status
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers, you can do it with pattern-matching:

```
opt match { case None => Error1; case Some(x) => Ok(x) }
```

since in this case the compiler *does* use type information from both branches and will look for a common type between `Error1` and `Ok(x)`.